# Problemas para actualizar ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

soy nuevo en el mundo de stackoverflow y linux, y estoy teniendo problemas para poder actualizar mi ubuntu, tanto desde la terminal como desde el programa "actualizacion de software". No se si este es el sitio indicado para este tipo de problemas, pero si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho[image: Por lo que puedo entender, tiene problemas con wine, pero ya lo desinstale y aun asi sigue el problema]

Mi distro:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Comment: Debes añadir los repositorios correctos de tu version de ubuntu,  creo que tienes mal los repositorios.

Comment: Como hago eso? o mejor dicho, como se cuales son los repositorios que debo añadir?

Comment: existe un archivo llamado sources.list que se encuentra en etc/apt/sources.list, ese es el que debes modificar, el tema es que aunque uso linux desde hace unos 2 meses siempre se me ha olvidado donde es que puedo encontrar los repositorios de mi versión de linux para poder añadirlos a mi linux, quizá ahora mas rato que me pase a linux (ya que estoy comentando en windows) vea que repositorios tengo configurados y te los pase en una respuesta.

Comment: De todas maneras lo que debes tener en cuenta a la hora de añadir esos repositorios es que la versión de los repositorios coincidan con tu version actual de linux (no intentes usar los de versiones diferentes, debe ser la que tienes).

Comment: Borra los repos que tengan que ver con wine

Answer (score 0):

Te está indicando que no tienes la llave pública del repositorio, podrías actualizarlo con:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>
```

Es decir:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 76F1A20FF987672F
```

Debería funcionar en Ubuntu, pues es lo mismo que en Debian.

Comment: Un error se soluciono, ahora quedo este                                                                       
             
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.